# Como zipar arquivos em um bucket do Cloud Storage, utilizando Python?

Tags: python, arquivo-zip, google-storage

Preciso zipar os arquivos presentes em um determinado `bucket do Cloud Storage`. Já tentei diversas alternativas, porém, até o momento sem sucesso. Por gentileza, poderiam me ajudar com esta questão?

No momento, estou conseguindo apenas retornar o nome dos blobs presentes no bucket, porém, preciso gerar um zip com todos os arquivos lá dentro e gravar no próprio bucket.

Segue código:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="file.json"

def zip_in_bucket(bucketname):

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucketname)
    object_generator = bucket.list_blobs()
    for files in object_generator:
        print(files.name)
```

Retorno:

```
file-1.csv
file-2.csv
file-3.csv
file-4.csv
file-5.csv
```

Comment: Não sei como você pode fazer isso direto do python. Mas uma saída é abrir os arquivos na sua VM, zipar cada um deles e depois rodar `gsutil mv *zip gs://nome_bucket/`. Muito mais ineficiente, though

Comment: Então Lucas, preciso fazer via Python mesmo, pois o processo precisará ser automatizado via Cloud Function.